# Is there a way to add a solid color after a threshold with scale_color_viridis_c from ggplot? Or to layer legends/color_bars with ggnewscale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

I'm trying to create a a plot for the accuracy of a set of models that differ in their combination of two parameters.
The accuracy doesn't exceed 0.98 for any model, and most of the models have an accuracy between 0.94 and 0.98 (btw it's just practice, no real research). I found that using `scale_color_viridis_c()` with `limits = c(.96, .98)` and `values = c(.25, 1)` yields a nice gradient, that visualizes the accuracy distrivution nicely, but this way I could not have the color_bar go up to 1 - it ends at 0.98.

My first approach was setting `limits = c(0.96, 1)` and `values = c(.125, 0.5)`, but that caused every value above 0.98 to register as NAs the same as the values below 0.96.
Then I tried layering this first plot with a second one that would be the same as the first one, but color the datapoints with an accuracy > 0.98 black (i.e. nothing) and "fill" the upper NAs (i.e. 0.98 to 1) of the first color_bar with black, and have everything lower transparent.

I created an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

set.seed(123)

# variable 1
v1 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:50) {
  v1 <- c(v1, rep(i, 56))
}

# variable 2
v2 <- rep(seq(50, 600, 10), 50)

# creating preliminary df
df <- data.frame(v1 = v1, v2 = v2)

# creating mock accuracy data
acc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  temp_acc <- runif(1, 1, 10) * x[1]^0.6 / x[2]^0.65 * -1
})
acc <- (-1 * (acc / (10 * min(acc)))) - runif(1, -0.01, 0.01) + 0.99
acc <- acc - (max(acc) - 0.98) - 0.0005

#create complete df
df$acc <- acc

#plotting
g <- ggplot(data =  df, aes(x  = v1, y = v2, color = acc)) +
  geom_point() + scale_color_viridis_c(values = c(.125, 0.5), na.value = "grey80",
                                       breaks = seq(0.96, 1, 0.005), limits = c(0.96, 1),
                                       guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10)) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(aes(color = acc), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = "black",
                        values = c(0.5, 1), na.value = NA,
                        breaks = seq(0.96, 1, 0.005), limits = c(0.96, 1),
                        guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10))
g
```

This does almost exactly what I want - the plot part is perfect, but I want the two color_bars to be combined into one. Is there a way to achieve this?
Or to approach it from a different angle: Is there a way to set two thresholds for a continuous color scale, and have data above/below those thresholds be colored differently whith a combined color_bar?

This is only for aesthetic reasons, and I could easily accomplish this task with image editing software, even MSPaint, but I'd like to be able to get it all done in R based on solely my data, no artificial editing.

Thanks in advance!

David

[plot with mock data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrOYL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to solve my problem, or at least a workaround that works well enough for me - the key was grabbing the the color values from `viridis()` directly, as you would with `rainbow()`. I tried it before and it didn't work because I didn't have `library(viridis)` loaded or specified it as `viridis::viridis()` so I wrongly concluded that there is nothing like `viridis()`.

But as it turns out, you can, so here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
library(viridis)

set.seed(123)

# variable 1
v1 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:50) {
  v1 <- c(v1, rep(i, 56))
}

# variable 2
v2 <- rep(seq(50, 600, 10), 50)

# creating preliminary df
df <- data.frame(v1 = v1, v2 = v2)

# creating mock accuracy data
acc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  temp_acc <- runif(1, 1, 10) * x[1]^0.6 / x[2]^0.65 * -1
})
acc <- (-1 * (acc / (10 * min(acc)))) - runif(1, -0.01, 0.01) + 0.99
acc <- acc - (max(acc) - 0.98) - 0.0005

# create complete df
df$acc <- acc

# grabbing the scale colors from viridis() and appending grey80,
# yielding a color vector that has the continuous viridis color of the length I need it,
# and then switches to a solid color of my choice
color_vector <- c(viridis(length(acc)), rep("grey80", times = length(acc)))

# plotting
g <- ggplot(data =  df, aes(x  = v1, y = v2, color = acc)) +
  geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = color_vector,
                                       values = c(0.2, 1), na.value = "grey45",
                                       guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = 15),
                                       breaks = seq(0.95, 1, 0.005),limits = c(0.95, 1))
g
```

I actually changed the (nonexistent) values above 0.98 to be represented in *"grey80"* instead of *"black"*, and the NA.values (i.e. everything below 0.96) from *"grey80"* to *"grey45"* - I found it to be more visually unambiguous that way.

Here's how it looks:
[imgurlink because I can't add pictures yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq2cn.png)

And thanks nonetheless for your suggestions, they will come in handy in other situations! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most 'programmatic' way to achieve what you want, as you'd have to hard-code the second set of limits, but you can get into the out-of-bounds behaviour of the scale. You can do this by setting the `oob` argument with a function of your own making. In this case, we'll wrap the `squish()` function from the scales package to have any values outside the limits become the nearest limit.

```r
#plotting
g <- ggplot(data =  df, aes(x  = v1, y = v2, color = acc)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_viridis_c(
    values = c(.125, 0.5), na.value = "grey80",
    breaks = seq(0.96, 1, 0.005), limits = c(0.96, 1),
    guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10),
    oob = function(x, ...){scales::squish(x, c(0.965, 0.98))}
  )
g
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's definitively useful, but not exactly what I was looking for in this case. I was hoping to show that there could be data points above the threshold, but there are none. In your solution one can't tell whether a yellow point is 0.98 or 0.99999.
Another workaround is using the rainbow color scale: [imgurlink](https://i.imgur.com/mzvQzGz.png). Here it is made very clear that the highest values are around 0.98, and but the scale shows clearly that even higher values would be distinguishable. But sadly the rainbow scale is not that colorblind-friendly (or pretty for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure I understood your question, but based on your example and what you want ("fuse" both scales) would this be ok? It doesn't need `ggnewscale`, much to my disappointment ️

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

# variable 1
v1 <- numeric()
for (i in 1:50) {
  v1 <- c(v1, rep(i, 56))
}

# variable 2
v2 <- rep(seq(50, 600, 10), 50)

# creating preliminary df
df <- data.frame(v1 = v1, v2 = v2)

# creating mock accuracy data
acc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  temp_acc <- runif(1, 1, 10) * x[1]^0.6 / x[2]^0.65 * -1
})
acc <- (-1 * (acc / (10 * min(acc)))) - runif(1, -0.01, 0.01) + 0.99
acc <- acc - (max(acc) - 0.98) - 0.0005

#create complete df
df$acc <- acc

#plotting
ggplot(data =  df, aes(x  = v1, y = v2, color = acc)) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha = acc >= .965)) + 
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.2, 1), guide = "none") +
  scale_color_viridis_c(values = c(.125, 0.5), na.value = "black",
                        breaks = seq(0.96, 1, 0.005), 
                        limits = c(0.96, 1),
                        guide = guide_colorbar(barheight = 10)) 
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Not entirely, I finally figured it out though, it was rather simple, and sadly also doesn't involve `ggnewscale` :D
I'll post it in a new answer so that I can properly present the code